# Reset or retreive Certificate generation key to Add Workflow host to existing WFFarm

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-server

I am configuring Workflow manager on a WFE to add to an existing SharePoint Farm.

Its asking for Certificate Generation key configured during farm creation. I dont have the key.

Could anyone help me how to get the Certificate Generation key from any existing host or reset it.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time when you build a workflow manager farm you have to create the certificate generation key. Just input the value which you want to use it, once enter then write it down because it is required if you add more servers in workflow manager farm.

It is same like passphrase in sharepoint farm, when you create a new farm, on very first config wizard you set it and for every server you add into farm, you input that passphrase.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-2016-part-five-configuration-of-workflow-manager

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to note the Workflow Certificate Generation Key and keep it safe, similar to how we did for PassPhrase during SharePoint Installation.

Yes you can reset the WF Certificate Generation Key using Workflow Manager PowerShell and then use it when you are joining your workflow manager/service bus to an existing workflow farm.

[Reset Certificate Generation Key for WorkFlowManager and ServiceBus](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2017/05/09/reset-certificate-generation-key-for-workflowmanager-and-servicebus/)